# Download a zip file using io.Pipe() read/write golang

Tags: go, zip, pipe, streamreader, writer

I am trying to stream out bytes of a zip file using io.Pipe() function in golang. I am using pipe reader to read the bytes of each file in the zip and then stream those out and use the pipe writer to write the bytes in the response object.

```
func main() {
  r, w := io.Pipe()
 // go routine to make the write/read non-blocking
  go func() {

    defer w.Close()

    bytes, err := ReadBytesforEachFileFromTheZip() 
    err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(bytes)
    handleErr(err)
  }()
```

This is not a working implementation but a structure of what I am trying to achieve. I don't want to use ioutil.ReadAll since the file is going to be very large and Pipe() will help me avoid bringing all the data into memory. Can someone help with a working implementation using io.Pipe() ?

Comment: You need to read the entire file. `zip.NewReader` takes an `io.ReaderAt`, which you can't do with a Pipe.

Comment: could not use io.Copy(zipReader, w) ? https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy

Comment: @mh-cbon I am not 100% sure but doesn't io.Copy use a buffer underneath ? I wanted to avoid that .

Comment: @JimB Isn't there a way to avoid reading the whole zip file somehow ? I am sure when zip file sizes are huge, no one wants to bring all the data into the memory. How about reading the bytes in chunks ? Curious, if it was a regular directory , can I use the Pipe ?

Comment: @psbits: that's how the zip format works. The central directory is located at the end of the file, so you can't (easily, or correctly) extract the files without first seeking to the end of the file and reading the directory.

Comment: yes, [there is a buffer for the operations](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go#L387). Anyway i double checked, and yes zipReader itself is not a Reader, so even io.copy won t work. You have to go through each files to get a reader.

Comment: @mh-cbonYup, I was trying that...looping over each file in the zip and reading it's bytes:
zf, err := zip.OpenReader("test.zip")
for _, file := range zf.File {
     fc, err := file.Open()
     // read bytes and pipe it ??
}
jimB mentioned we cannot use Pipe here to read the bytes and pass it to the writer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using golang io.Pipe().The Pipewriter writes byte to the pipe in chunks and the pipeReader reader from the other end. The reason for using a go-routine is to have a non-blocking write operation while simultaneous reads happen form the pipe.

Note: It's important to close the pipe writer (w.Close()) to send EOF on the stream otherwise it will not close the stream.

```
func DownloadZip() ([]byte, error) {
    r, w := io.Pipe()

    defer r.Close()
    defer w.Close()

    zip, err := os.Stat("temp.zip")
    if err != nil{
        return nil, err
    }

    go func(){

        f, err := os.Open(zip.Name())
        if err != nil {
            return

        }

        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        for {
            chunk, err := f.Read(buf)
            if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
                panic(err)
            }
            if chunk == 0 {
                break
            }

            if _, err := w.Write(buf[:chunk]); err != nil{
                return
            }

        }

        w.Close()
    }()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return body, nil

}
```

Please let me know if someone has another way of doing it.

Comment: The goroutine and pipe are pointless here. You're still reading the file synchronously, just adding another copy for no reason.

Comment: @JimB Could you explain how is the grouting/pipe pointless here ? The go routine is making the pipe writer write to the pipe in chunks and without blocking the pipe reader read from the other end. I do agree it's a sort of copy but then that wouldn't that copy all the data at once ? May be I could use copyN.

Comment: Any read/copy has to happen in chunks, so I'm not sure what you mean by "all at once". What you have here is a less-efficient version of `io.Copy`, but there's no need to copy at all since `ioutil.ReadAll` is going to read the entire file into memory anyway, so just use that directly.

Comment: That makes sense. What I was trying to achieve using the io.Pipe() was to write chunks of data to the pipe and read it from the other end , so I don't have to bring all the data into memory together. Is there a way I can achieve that @jimB ?

Comment: The pipe is irrelevant. You use a pipe to synchronously connect something that takes a `io.Reader` to something that takes an `io.Writer`. That is all. Reading the entire file into memory at once or not is strictly up to you -- i.e. if you don't want to read it all don't use `ReadAll`. You seem to have an XY problem here, and you need to show what you're trying to accomplish, rather than what you _think_ you need to do.